# can findAll be used to connect to an content api?

Tags: canjs, canjs-model

can findAll be used to connect to an content api and then get all the data and then can we use the findone to filter the data depending upon the id or the field

Answer (score 1):

The CanJS cached model plugin handles a similar use case; I think the only difference is that it will go out and do a findOne on the server if the object isn't located in the cache.  You could easily modify it so that it did a findAll with the loosest possible params for your content source instead.

https://github.com/bitovi/canjs/blob/master/model/cached/cached.js